# Implement timeline panel like google chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, timeline

I am a novice in HTML5 and Javascript and am trying to implement a view similar to google timeline panel for my webpage. (https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/timeline)

I did refer to a few questions on SO for this but the gantt chart and jqPlot libraries don't seem to have all these cool features. Any suggestions on how to get started on this? I tried looking for source code for the timeline panel but couldn't find it either.

Thanks

Comment: You can  handle this type of a view with backbone.js views and models.
Dividing the widgets in small independent views and write bindings for user interactions

Comment: Thanks Ajeet. Please pardon my ignorance but can you please elaborate on this? I took a quick look at backbone.js tutorials and demos but couldn't find something I am looking for.